# need a code for this question "gap filling" time series

Tags: r

I have daily time series as provided in the example here, I need to know how to fill the NA value for only the morning time which is starting from 6:00 AM to 9:00 AM, that gap filling it should be by averaging the residual hours of the same day and so on for the other morning day,

```
set.seed(3)
df <- data.frame( timestamp = seq(as.POSIXct('2022-01-01', tz='utc'),as.POSIXct('2022-01-10 23:00', tz='utc'), by = '1 hour') ,
                  value = runif(240))
df$value[runif(nrow(df)) < 0.3] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly this is one way to solve the task in dplyr:

```
df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(after = ifelse(lubridate::hour(timestamp) > 10, value, NA), 
                  day = format(df$timestamp, format = '%Y-%m-%d')) %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(day) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(value = ifelse(lubridate::hour(timestamp) <10 & is.na(value), mean(after, na.rm = TRUE), value)) %>% 
    dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
    dplyr::select(-after, -day)

# A tibble: 240 x 2
   timestamp           value
   <dttm>              <dbl>
 1 2022-01-01 00:00:00 0.427
 2 2022-01-01 01:00:00 0.808
 3 2022-01-01 02:00:00 0.385
 4 2022-01-01 03:00:00 0.427
 5 2022-01-01 04:00:00 0.602
 6 2022-01-01 05:00:00 0.604
 7 2022-01-01 06:00:00 0.125
 8 2022-01-01 07:00:00 0.295
 9 2022-01-01 08:00:00 0.578
10 2022-01-01 09:00:00 0.631
# ... with 230 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but actually when I applied this code I got NaN value instead of the average

Comment: @Jon please could include a second sample data set which produces the error or NaN? My guess is that there are cases where you have no non NA value to produce the mean from the "after" hours. Because if you try mean(c(NA, NA, NA), na.rm = TRUE) you get NaN (not a number)... if in fact the problem is caused by only NAs to build a mean over we would need a definition of how to treat these cases after working the mean solution

Comment: @Jon 
I tested the case I described and you can reproduce this using "df[11:24, "value"] <- NA" on your sample data which set all after hours of the first day to NA and it produces NaN if you run the code. So this indicates strongly but does not proof the cause of your problem... let me know how to impute these cases and I am positive that we get the solution

Answer (score 0):

timestamp             value after day
                  
1 2022-01-01 00:00:00 NaN        NA 00
2 2022-01-01 01:00:00   0.808    NA 01
3 2022-01-01 02:00:00   0.385    NA 02
4 2022-01-01 03:00:00 NaN        NA 03
5 2022-01-01 04:00:00   0.602    NA 04
6 2022-01-01 05:00:00   0.604    NA 05
7 2022-01-01 06:00:00   0.125    NA 06
8 2022-01-01 07:00:00   0.295    NA 07
9 2022-01-01 08:00:00   0.578    NA 08
10 2022-01-01 09:00:00   0.631    NA 09

## ... with 230 more rows

## i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).